# Laravel: Class not found Exception

Tags: php, laravel, shared-hosting

In my Laravel project, if have a file app/lib/*Formatter.php*, with an class Formatter.
From a Controller i am importing this php file using `use App\Lib\Formatter;`
In my local development enviroment, I can access methods from the Formatter in my Controller. But when i deploy the laravel project to a share hosting, i can't access Formatter. Laravel returns this error message:

> "Class 'App\Lib\Formatter' not found"

After it works localy, i don't have any idea, why it shouldn't work on shared hosting.

Comment: Case matters. If it's in `app/lib/Formatter.php`, you need `App\lib\Formatter`, with the lowercase L. (NB: `App`/`app` is a special case, via rules in `composer.json`.)

Comment: It could be a casing issue. Change the folder name from `lib` to `Lib`. Some OS's care about casing (specifically Linux), while others don't (specially Windows (and Mac, if I'm not mistaken)).

Comment: Case din't matter for other imports. And localy it's working with upper case

Comment: @no0by5 As Magnus noted, some operating systems *aren't* case sensitive. That's probably why it works in one place and not another.

Comment: Does your class have the namespace in the correct case? The casing _must_ be consistent everywhere if you want it to be compatible with all the OS's.

Comment: in Formatter.php:
namespace App\Lib;

Comment: there are several other imports with use/app/mail etc. that are working

Comment: Have you **tried** our suggestion? We see this question a lot around here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linux is casesensitive. You should rename your folder from `lib` to `Lib`.

If your folder tree looks like `App\lib\Formatter.php` rename your library to `App\Lib\Formatter.php`.

Comment: Composer should really have taken care of that . It isn't really an issue with the `app` folder why is it an issue with the `lib` folder?

Comment: I renamed `lib` to `Lib` and it's working now.. what a stupid error.. thank you

Comment: Fortunatelly it is not an error. Linux and Windows have different engine. Linux has more and stronger policies and rules.